# How to change text color when doing go to file in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to use the `Go to file` function in vscode but it is hard to see the text when I am typing. This issue is only for the [`macOs Classic theme`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=huacnlee.theme-macos-classic), and working when I changed the color theme. Any idea how can I modify the text color? Please see the image below.

**Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: search for theme color customization, find the name of the color and change it for this theme only

Comment: @rioV8 what property should I use?

Comment: there is a long list of all the theme colors, and the list is finite and not all color names affect the particular list color